# why is this conditional statement using comparison operators incorrect?

Tags: python, python-3.x, conditional-statements, comparison-operators

This is a small element of a larger script. Through trial and error I have found that this is the offending line:

```
>>> print('lower than all') if (3 < (2 and 9 and 9)) is True else print('false')
lower than all
```

This is clearly incorrect. However changing to **this** gives the right answer:

```
>>> print('lower than all') if 3 < (2 and 9 and 9) is True else print('false')
false
```

I have simplified the example, in reality all the numbers are variables being checked. I really don't understand the difference here!

Again why does this work correctly?!

```
>>> print('lower than all') if 3 < 2 and 9 and 9 is True else print('false')
false
```

Comment: Easiest way to understand these is to break them down chunk by chunk.

Comment: None of these work correctly, they're all fundamentally wrong and failing in different ways.

Comment: There's too much going on here to give just one answer. Like, why are you checking `is True`? That's redundant for testing a boolean expression. And why is there a redundant `9`? Most importantly, what are you expecting `2 and 9 and 9` to mean? I think this is ultimately a duplicate of these questions: [How to test multiple variables for equality against a single value?](/q/15112125/4518341), [Why does "a == x or y or z" always evaluate to True?](/q/20002503/4518341)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to lead with this: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. Check out [ask], which has tips like how to refine your question.

Comment: Another duplicate: [Comparison operators and 'is' - operator precedence in python?](/q/32182177/4518341)

Comment: After reading it over again, it looks like every aspect of what you're asking is covered by those questions, so I've closed it accordingly. But my points about the redundant `is True` and `and 9` are still relevant.

Comment: Oops, one aspect the other questions don't cover is how to do multiple comparisons besides `==`. One sec, lemme find another one...

Comment: BTW, the second `print()` is redundant. You can do something like `print(x if condition else y)`

Answer (score 0):

If you see this chunk, it returns `9`

```
>>> 2 and 9 and 9
9
```

To understand this, take a look at how the `and` operation between integers works. From the [official doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#and):

> The expression `x and y` first evaluates *x*; if *x* is false, its value is returned; otherwise, *y* is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

In this case, `2` is true, `9` is true and the final `9` is also true. Here, the last `9` is `y` and that's the value being returned.

Try out `2 and 1` and you'll see `1` as the result.

Due to this, your statement

```
print('lower than all') if (3 < (2 and 9 and 9)) is True else print('false')
```

Actually becomes

```
print('lower than all') if (3 < 9) is True else print('false')
```

And prints 'lower than all'

Comment: I just edited this to fix the details. You wrote that "`2` returns `True`", which is not really how that works. Look into ["truthy" and "falsy"](/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false) to understand it better.